# struct and union name collision

Tags: c, struct, unions

I wrote a simple test program and tried to use this:

```
union FLT { ... };
struct FLT { ... };
```

But compiler complained about naming collision.

Since in C you need to use `struct` and `union` befor your tag name, why would they collide?

I mean when we want to declare a variable of type `stuct FLT` named `num` we'd use

```
struct FLT num;
```

and when we want to use a variable named `diffnum` of type `union FLT` we'd use

```
union FLT diffnum;
```

So why couldn't compiler differentiates them?

BTW I tested both MinGW and VC, if you need to know.

**UPDATE**

```
union FLOAT {
        float value;
        unsigned int bits;
        unsigned char bytes[4];
};
struct FLOAT {
        unsigned int sign;
        unsigned int exponent;
        unsigned int significand;
};
union FLOAT num;
struct FLOAT num_parts;
```

I was using this code to do some floating point arithmetic tests.

Comment: It is interesting to mention that in C++ you don't write `struct` or `enum` when declaring such variables.

Comment: yeah, that's right, and that's one of the reasons that this behavior seems odd to me. C++ doesn't mandate their use, so when C mandates their use, why the compiler couldn't or wouldn't use this extra bit of information?

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.2.3 **Name spaces of identifiers** says: — _the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any(32)
of the keywords `struct`, `union`, or `enum`);_ and footnote 32 says: _There is only one name space for tags even though three are possible._  So, the standard recognizes the possibility of separate namespaces for the tags of `struct`, `union` and `enum` types — but consciously chose not to separate them, probably based on prior art (no compiler did separate them).

Comment: It *does* use it, but for a *single* tag namespace. C++ designers found this confusing already but couldn't get rid of tag names for compatibility, so they introduced extra rules like a normal identifier *collides* with a tag *except* when it identifies the exact same type, which I find even more confusing, but that's just *my* opinion..

Comment: @FelixPalmen: There's the issue of `struct stat { ... }` and function `int stat(const char *filename, struct stat *sb)` to make life fun in C++.  Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @FelixPalmen - One gets used to it. Also, C++ has user defined namespaces. So it isn't much of a loss really.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Is that really an issue? You can always disambiguate the type by a `struct` keyword, and there is no ambiguity for the function call.

Comment: @StoryTeller: it is a known issue.  Normally in C++, when you define `struct stat` the name `stat` becomes a type name too, but the `stat()` system call isn't a constructor for the `stat` type.  I'm not clear of all the ins and outs, but the rules of C++ had to be designed to accommodate this specific example of C legacy causing headaches for C++.

Comment: That's exactly one incarnation of the issue, yes. In an attempt to simplify this "tag business", C++ IMHO made it worse instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I know it's a type name too. And if both identifiers are visible then `stat sb;` is ill-formed. But `struct stat sb; stat(..., &sb);` is perfectly valid C++. But I suppose you are right, and that's why C++ had to retain the "elaborate type specifier" way of naming tagged types.

Comment: @StoryTeller: The issue is called out by Stroustrup in "Design and Evolution", section 2.8.2 Structure Tags vs Type Names (on p48).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They collide because all "tagged types" share one namespace for the tags.

[**C11 6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers (N1570 Draft)**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3)

> If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at
>   any point in a translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates
>   uses that refer to different entities. Thus, there are separate name
>   spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> - label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
> - **the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations** (disambiguated by following any of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
> - the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the
>     expression used to access the member via the . or -> operator);
> - all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on WHY C standard requires this behavior?

Comment: A **why** doesn't make much sense for an SO question, this would be completely speculative.

Comment: @m0h4mm4d - I couldn't since I'm not on the committee that defines the standard. That's just the way they defined it (and not changed since 1989).

Comment: Yeah, I understand but do you have any idea about the rationale? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @m0h4mm4d - Well, [there is a rationale document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) for C99. Where the various positions of the committee members are details by standard section. However, if you turn to page 34 where the above paragraph is mentioned, it doesn't say much about anything.

Comment: maybe because nobody *needs* to write such confusing code? You could ask the other way around why e.g. *shadowing* is allowed although confusing...

Comment: *"Any thoughts...?"* How about some pure speculation?  Perhaps the first compiler stored information about declared `struct`s and `union`s in a common data structure, the only difference being that the offset stored for each field in the object was 0 for a `union` and the sum of the sizes of the previous fields for a `struct`.

Comment: Early C compilers were very simple. It was probably done just to avoid having to have separate symbol tables for each type.

Comment: One could argue however that allowing separate namespaces for each tag would not break existing code, and could therefore be proposed to the ISO C committee.

Comment: It depends on how early an 'early compiler' you want to go to.  In the first versions with structure support, the names of structure members had to be unique across all structures, and you could play all sorts of games with using a name of the same type and offset in unrelated structures.  It didn't take long before each structure (or union) got a separate namespace for its members, which made it much easier to code reliably.

Comment: @FelixPalmen With all due respect, that kind of thinking would turn C into C# or Java! Why do we use pointers in C? Why programmers are burdened with memory management? We turn to C because of that stuff. Or at least I do.

Comment: @m0h4mm4d no it wouldn't. Show **one** good usage of shadowing that's not possible with basically the *same* code but less opportunity of confusion.

Comment: @StoryTeller you *could* propose that, but it's not enough that it doesn't hurt existing code -- you have to show it would be actually *useful* as well, and I doubt that...

Comment: @FelixPalmen Is it alright to add a simple code snippet to my question to show you guys what I'm doing? Sorry, I'm new to SO.

Comment: @m0h4mm4d - You can add a code snippet, sure. Just don't change the original meaning of the question if you do.

Comment: @m0h4mm4d as long as it doesn't change the meaning of the question in a way that invalidates this existing answer, it's fine! So you can show that you would do something *useful* with different tag namespaces?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yeah, I'm gonna take my chances. :D Maybe you guys have something to say about what I was gonna do.