# Can't we use same name for a variable and function in C programming

Tags: c, function

Is the error message due to same variable and function name?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumOfSquare(int x, int y);

int main() {
    int a, b, sumOfSquare;

    printf("Enter Number 1 : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);  

    printf("Enter Number 2 : ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    sumOfSquare = sumOfSquare(a, b);

    printf("Sum of square of %d and %d :%d", a, b, sumOfSquare);
}

int sumOfSquare(int x, int y) {
    return x * x + y * y;
}
```

I got a error message:

```
Q2.c: In function 'main':
Q2.c:13:13: error: called object 'sumOfSquare' is not a function or function pointer
 sumOfSquare = sumOfSquare(a, b);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
Q2.c:5:9: note: declared here
 int a, b, sumOfSquare;
```

Comment: The `sumOfSquare` defined in `main` is *shadowing* the function name. The compiler is saying that `sumOfSquare(a,b)` is not a function. The error does not occur at `int sumOfSquare;` in `main` but at the function call `sumOfSquare = sumOfSquare(a, b);`

Comment: Giving them the same name isn't the best idea regardless.

Comment: a little fun: https://ideone.com/lXpQPm

Answer (score 4):

Just about any<sup>1</sup> identifier may be reused, as long as it is in a different (nested) [*scope*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope) (or [*name space*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/name_space)).

`int sumOfSquare(int x, int y);` is a function defined at *file scope*, whereas `int sumOfSquare;` is an object defined at *block scope* (an inherently nested scope relative to *file scope*). These two definitions share a name space ("*ordinary identifiers*").

The *block scope* definition [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the *file scope* definition.

At the point of

```
sumOfSquare = sumOfSquare(a, b);
```

the identifier `sumOfSquare` refers entirely to the `int` object, and the function is no longer visible - hence the error about trying to *call* something that is not a function.

---

<sup>1. There are exceptions with regards to [*reserved identifiers*](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3).</sup>

Comment: So you *can* (re-)use the same name for different things, but only one of the definitions is available at any given point in the source code. In C++, one can qualify names with namespace or class prefixes (e.g. use `myClass::i` to refer to a class member but `::i` to refer to a global variable) in the same source location. I think nothing like that is possible to distinguish scopes in C?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Namespaces and scopes are independent concepts, but namespaces often mitigate the problem since they're no longer the same name. C has nothing analogous to namespaces.

Comment: @Barmar well, `int i; int main() { int i = 2; return ::i + i; }` returns 2, i.e. `::i` refers to the file scope i... essentially solving the OP's issue. `int i() { return 1; } int main() { int i = 2; return ::i() + i; }` is a faithful reproduction.

Comment: By the way, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45408848/3150802 mentions the different identifier categories in C. *Between* those categories there are no clashes, *within* them there are. Most notably, struct names and members do not clash with variables or functions.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Have you not read the documentation I have *already* linked ([Lookup and name spaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/name_space)), which is also reiterated, albeit tersely, by my answer?

Comment: @OK I'm sorry, I had not. Mea culpa. Anyway, the following program may be amusing: `struct i { int i; }; int i; int main() { i: if( (struct i){i}.i) goto i; return i; }`.

Comment: The code could be `int main(void) { int (*function)(int x, int y) = SumOfSquare; /* This refers to the function */ int SumOfSquare; /* This is a local variable shadowing the function */ … SumOfSquare = (*function)(a, b); /* Or: SumOfSquare = function(a, b); */ … return 0; }`. This shows that the name `SumOfSquare` can have different meanings in a single scope when the scope is identified by `{ … }`.

Answer (score 2):

C has four different "name spaces" for identifiers:

- Label names (distinguished by the `goto` keyword and the colon `:`);
- Tag names for struct/enum/union types (distinguished by the `struct`, `enum`, and `union` keywords);
- Struct and union member names (distinguished by appearing in a struct or union definition and the `.` or `->` member selection operators in an expression; each struct or union type acts as a different namespace so you can use the same member names in different struct or union definitions);
- All other names (variable names, function names, typedef names, enumeration constants, etc.);

So, you can use the same identifier for different things in the same scope *as long as those identifiers belong to different namespaces*:

```
     struct foo {       // tag namespace
       int foo;         // struct foo member namespace
       double bar;      // struct foo member namespace 
     };

     struct bar {       // tag namespace
       double foo;      // struct bar member namespace
       int bar;         // struct bar member namespace
     };

     struct foo         // tag namespace
       foo;             // all other names

     struct bar         // tag namespace
       bar;             // all other names

     goto foo;          // label namespace
     ...
foo:                    // label namespace
     printf( 
       "foo.foo = %d\n", 
       foo.foo );       // all other names, struct foo member namespace
```

Don't ever do that.

Anyway, `foo` can be a struct tag name *and* a member name *and* a label name *and* a variable name all in the same scope, because those are all in different name spaces.

`foo` *cannot* be a variable name *and* a function name or a typedef name or an enumeration constant in the same scope, because those are all in the same namespace.  In your case, the use of `sumOfSquare` as a variable name in `main` "shadows" or hides the use of `sumOfSquare` as a function name.

Answer (score 0):

Although as others have stated, if there is a function `sumOfSquares` at file scope but the variable `sumOfSquares` exists at block scope, so there is a collision. Well, why not just store variables and functions in a different namespace, so that if you try calling a name it looks for a function and if you try using it in any other way it looks for a variable of the name?

The answer is you can actually use functions as 'variables' and vice versa. Enter the [function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/840501/16217248). You could have defined a function `int sumOfSquare(int, int)` but then you could do this:

```
int (*function_pointer)(int, int);
function_pointer = sumOfSquare; /* Treating sumOfSquare as a value
    that can be assigned to function_pointer */
int result = function_pointer(10, 20); /* Treating the function_pointer
    as a function */
```

This makes whether any given symbol is a 'function' or a 'variable' non-deterministic. Therefore, no, C could not have just made you able to declare functions as the same name as variables by handling them separately by storing them in a separate namespace.

Note that this does not apply to function-like macros. If `sumOfSquare` is a macro function instead of a 'real' function, defined as something presumably like:

```
#define sumOfSquare(x, y) ((x)*(x)+(y)*(y))
```

Then:

```
int sumOfSquare = sumOfSquare(a, b);
```

**Would** be valid.

Comment: For your macro example, I'd explain that in `int sumOfSquare = sumOfSquare(a, b);` the rightmost `sumOfSquare(a, b)` _is_ expanded as a macro because the number of arguments _matches_ the definition (i.e.) `(a, b)` and `(x, y)`. But, the leftmost `int sumOfSquare` is _not_ interpreted as a macro call because the number of arguments does _not_ match.

Comment: This is horrible. Why obfuscate even more? The solution is to use distinct identifier names.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not saying that you should do this, I'm saying that you can if you want to.

Comment: You can invent you own langauge by using macros, but it will be unreadable.